# How many votes are needed to delete a question?

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

I've noticed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079986/operatornameend-bbb-z-is-a-commutative-ring-while-operatornameend-b/) that only three votes have been enough to delete a question. Isn't this too few?

(To be clear: I don't care about my answer there, although I care about the comments under the question where I've clarified to another user that $\operatorname{End}(R)$ is not necessarily a group when one considers the *ring* endomorphisms of a given ring $R$.)

Comment: The question you linked to is now undeleted. If it is supposed to last on the site, it should probably be edited (clarified, added context).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions

> It takes 3 votes, minimum, to delete a closed question. However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.

The number of votes required can increase a lot, recently there was a question that took six votes to be deleted. As for whether three isn't enough... You have to realize that for it to happen, the question needs to have been closed for at least 48h, and three 10k users have to spend their very limited deletion votes on your question. That's a stringent requirement.

As for the lost comments... Comments are supposed to be ephemeral, the focus of this website is on questions/answers. I don't even think comments turn up in a (SE) search. If you believe that observation is of lasting value to the website, you can post a question and self-answer it.

Comment: If someone wants to now more about *how* are the number of votes scaled based on question popularity, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) is a post about this I was able to find.

Comment: Comments are not used by SE search engine. But Google search of course includes comments. (I guess Google does not has much of possibility how to differentiate between answers and comments. And Google indexes the whole webpage anyway.) You can try [this search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Asaf+insert+joke+site%3Ameta.math.stackexchange.com) - if you check the hits, in several cases the keywords only appear in the comments.

Comment: @MartinSleziak You seem to be right (I just tested). (There are ways to tell Google what part of a webpage is what, as far as I know, using "rich snippets" and whatnot. I probably overestimated what these things were capable of, though)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like a negative score on the question itself can offset positive scored answers in terms of not requiring more than 3 delete votes.  Also, I think 20k+ users don't have to wait 48 hours.

Comment: @Isaac 20k (trusted) users don't have to wait 48h only if the question is at -3 or lower.